# No se revierte el contenido al fallar en las consultas

Tags: java, sql

Estoy probando las transacciones en un código muy simple, y no encuentro el fallo que tengo, ya que no se me revierte el contenido al fallar en las consultas...
Tengo el autocommit a false, el commit después de la ejecución y el rollback al final... La ejecución llega hasta (revertido) pero aún así los cambios no se revierten.
¡Dejo el código! (¡La instrucción 2 da fallo para comprobar la transacción!)

```java
public class Transacciones2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso_php", "root", "");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();


            String instruccion1 = "DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAIS='ITALIA'";
            String instruccion2 = "DELETE FROM PRODUCTOSsss WHERE PRECIO>100";
            String instruccion3 = "UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRECIO=PRECIO*1.15";

            boolean eleccion = ejecutar_transaccion();
            if (eleccion) {
                statement.executeUpdate(instruccion1);
                statement.executeUpdate(instruccion2);
                statement.executeUpdate(instruccion3);
                connection.commit();
                System.out.println("Todo Perfecto");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Algo ha salido mal, revirtiendo . . .");
            try {
                assert connection != null;
                connection.rollback();
                System.out.println("revertido . . .");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("No se ha podido recuperar el cambio . . .");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean ejecutar_transaccion() {
        String e = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quieres ejecutar el programa?");
        if (e.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ejecuto un código basado en el que muestras y en mi caso funciona correctamente el rollback.

Comment: Puede estar relacionado con la configuración de mi base de datos MySQL? Gracias por la ayuda!